# SSRS - Expression to replace all but last four characters?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2005

Apologies in advance if question is too basic. I searched but couldn't find anything specifically applicable to reporting services.

I'm working on a report that's currently returning the full value that's being queried.

Currently, the expression for that text field is

`=Fields!VarName.Value`

What I'm looking to do is return only the last four with a set of *s to represent whatever the preceding digits are. Even though the number of digits is going to vary, it's not important that I match digit for digit, so I'm fine with just inserting a set number of *s and then the last four. I figured this would be easier. I've tried this:

`="*****" & Right(Fields!VarName.Value,4)`

That returns the stars, but not the actual values. Am I just completely off the mark on how to get those last four numbers?

Comment: You might have trailing spaces in your data. Try .. `Right(RTRIM(Fields!VarName.Value),4)`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much! Still trying to RTFM enough to figure things out. Just needed a nudge.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer so that the questions can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

"Right(RTRIM(Fields!VarName.Value),4)" Was the correct answer.